# Get data from class with two array class Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class with two array, i need this class to work with it in tableview so this is my code

```
class X {
    private var abc: [Demo]!
    private var def: [Project]!
    init() {  
    }
    init(abc:[Demo], def:[Project]) {
        self.abc = abc
        self.def = def
    }
}
```

So how can i get access to class Demo and Class Project, i have already the data in class X

class Demo like this

```
class Demo {
   private var nom:String

  init(nom:String) {
    self.nom = nom
}
```

and class Project like this

```
    class Project {
    private var title:String 
    init(title:String){
       self.title = tile
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get access"? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Hi @Uncommon i want ti get nom and title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted the code where you're trying to access the data, but your problem may be that you have declared `nom` and `title` as `private` which makes them inaccessible to other classes. Try deleting `private`.

If you just want to prevent other classes from changing them, you can change `private` to `public private(set)`.

Answer (score 0):

what 's mean of "get access"?
If your property  in  class Demo and Project is private , so you must have a get function to access to property in it